# Enabling CORS in MVC application (to be deployed on azure)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, cors, azure-active-directory

I know there are a number of questions on this forum stating the same problem statement. But i wanted to present my particular scenario to get the guideline/suggestion related to that. 
i am working on an MVC application that is supposed to be deployed on azure (basically it deals with windows azure using .net sdk and other packages). Application works perfectly but **after 50 -60 minutes of idle time** (i.e. without refreshing), the connect is lost. 
During debugging the code (through Visual Studio 2015 community edition) i have found that it redirects the flow to Sign in () function (i have not developed that function so i don't have through understanding of that). Here it creates a sign in url (to authenticate with azure AD)and redirects the application to that url. This is the point where application gives error. In browser (Google Chrome) console i found it stating

> MLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.windows.net/common/wsfed?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2fdhttps%253a%252f%252flocalhost%253a43778%252f&wct=2016-09-26T19%3a05%3a59Z. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:43778' is therefore not allowed access.

I tried to enable CORS in the application using almost all the methods i.e.

- Using web.config entries
- Using nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors version 5.2.2 and 5.2.3, enabling it globally though webapiconfig.cs and/or controller, action level.

Nothing is seeming to be helping and i can't find headers related to CORS in Requests and responses. 
What could be the problem with enabling CORS. Please guide.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

**Edit:**
Actually Application behaves like this while idle, once we refresh the page it's all okay. I was just investigating why the connection is lost and how to keep the application up even after such long idle time. If any thing other than CORS can cause this problem please guide and suggest the possible fix.

Comment: Why is it showing 'https://localhost:43778 if the site is deployed on Azure? Did you update the Azure Active Directory Application with the web app or web site URL?

Comment: CORS rules are specified on the **receiving** side. In this case `login.windows.net/`. This means login.windows.net has specified that your application is not allowed. Not the other way around. This is not something you can change yourself.

Comment: @Haitham site is not actually deployed yet but i am debugging it on localhost and yeah i have updated Azure ADD application with this url

Comment: Sorry, my bad, can you show us how do you redirect to the AAD login page?

Comment: Well, its a sign in function that redirects to sign in url in return "return new RedirectResult(signInRequest.RequestUrl.ToString());"

Answer (score 2):

Yeah well the CORS header is not missing in your app. It's missing from login.windows.net. If you redirected to that page it shouldn't be a CORS problem. CORS only comes into play when you make a call from JavaScript to another domain. Check the JS AJAX calls. Something is trying to call to login.windows.net, and it's not the redirect.

Comment: Then y can't i alteast see 'origin' header  in my request headers? which i am specifying in code (while enabling CORS).

Comment: and isn't it a cross domain request where app on localhost requests 'login.windows.net'. It's server side code that is redirecting, "return new RedirectResult(signInRequest.RequestUrl.ToString());"

Comment: Server returns an HTTP 302 redirect, browser goes to URL, not a request where CORS is involved. Only when the JavaScript code makes an HTTP call does the browser look at the call, and if it is cross-domain, makes an HTTP OPTIONS request to figure out if the call would be okay. You are having a problem with something related to authentication. I would suggest learning how the whole app works.

Comment: It seems like the app is secured using WsFed auth.  The javascript is making a request to some controller on the app, and the session has expired.  The server then returns a 302 redirect to `login.windows.net`, and the js follows it.  As juunas mentions Azure AD doesn't support CORS.

Whatever APIs the js is calling via AJAX will need to be secured in a way that returns 401s. The js then needs to catch the 401 and redirect the window to Azure AD for login.  Good post here: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/04/28/use-owin-azure-ad-to-secure-both-mvc-ux-and-web-api-in-the-same-project/